# How to configure a MySQL DataSource on Grails 3.1.x with web-api profile?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I already use Grails since v1.3.x and now I'm not having success with the DataSource/GORM configuration...

My steps were:
1 - $ grails create-app myApi --profile=web-api.

2 - Configure the *application.yml* file with:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test-app
```

3 - On *build.gradle* file, replace the runtime dependency **"com.h2database:h2"** with **"mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"**

4 - Create a database called **test-app**

5 - Create a domain: $grails create-domain-class MyDomain

6 - Add a String attribute on MyDomain classe called *name*
Example:

```
package myapi

class MyDomain {
    String name
    static constraints = { }
}
```

7 - Run the app: **$grails run-app**
Output:

> Running application...
>   objc[27851]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development

And no tables were created... anyone knows what step I'm missing in here?

OBS.: Even if I misspelled the database name, the app still running and no error happens.

Comment: When I tried to save an instance of MyDomain, a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException occurs with this message: "Method on class [myapi.MyDomain] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate plugin are not include by default as a normal dependency on **Grails 3.1.0.M2** with *web-api* profile, so in order to fix this you just have to add in your dependencies:

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.7"
```

More info at: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9366